# Css animation queue

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a troublesome task. Image should be hidden and button showed by default. I want to show image and hide button, but when one animation ends, secound should start. transition should peroid 1 second. How to make it?

All code:
https://jsfiddle.net/169vuuk8/

HTML code:

```
<div class="showSingle" itemprop="1">
  <img src="https://img.thegearpage.net/board/data/avatars/m/47/47608.jpg?1487188345" alt="logo">
  <button class="button">button </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @keyframe is your friend

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need `transition-delay` css property for second animation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay

You can either use `transitionend` event in js, but it is not really needed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need exactly but below the image fades in the first second and the button out after 2 seconds delay.

```css
.showSingle img {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInImage 1s ease-out forwards;
}

.showSingle button {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fadeOutButton 1s ease-out 2s forwards;}

@keyframes fadeInImage {
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutButton {
  to {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="showSingle" itemprop="1">
  <img src="https://img.thegearpage.net/board/data/avatars/m/47/47608.jpg?1487188345" alt="logo">
  <button class="button">button </button>
</div>
```

Comment: on hover, img should hide, after that animation button should show